response.message is undefined
I want to get the Error-Message that is currently happening if something is wrong while I fetch.
But it just throws out undefined, but the response.message is given as you can see in the Console.
I can't figure out how I can access this Message, can somebody help me?
I tried this way
await fetch(url).then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log(response.message);
    $("#errorMessage").text("Error " + response.status);
    $(".reload").show();
    return false;
  }
  return response.json();
});

And expected to get this Message:


you'll need to access the response body using response.json() - the message will be in there - oh, and stop using async/await with .then ... use one or the other, there is hardly ever a reason to use both in one function, and this is not hardly ever

Thanks the fast reply and the tip.
I tried ist but I can't access the message.
The respone.json() looks like this:
Promise <state>: "fullfilled" <value>: { success: false, message: "Too many requests, please try again later." }

yes, it's a Promise, you seem to know how to handle those ... anyway - posted an answer

Show you you tried to use response.json(); did you await it?

Clearly you're in an async function, and partly using async/await and partly .then
this gets messy
Pick one and stick with it
Either
const response = await fetch(url);
if (!response.ok) {
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.message);
    $('#errorMessage').text('Error ' + response.status);
    $('.reload').show();
    return false;
}
return response.json();

Or
fetch(url)
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.message);
            $('#errorMessage').text('Error ' + response.status);
            $('.reload').show();
            return false;
        });
    }
    return response.json();
})


It worked, thanks!
I will stick to your advice with async and await, you're the best!

Since it worked, please mark their answer as correct.
